# Should I book flights for multiple people together or separately?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, ryanair, group-travel

I am trying to book a Ryanair flight, which gives me one price (Say £50) per person if I book one person, but a higher price (say £60) when I try to book 4 people. Is there any way we can arrange to all book separately at the same time to get the same solo price, or do we have to book together and take the hit? Does anyone have any general advice?

Comment: Bear in mind that on Ryanair, you won't be guaranteed seats together even if you book together unless you pay an extra fee to choose your seat (indeed, there is evidence that Ryanair deliberately separates parties in order to further incentive passengers to pay this fee).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get a higher price for a booking for multiple persons, then most likely there are not enough seats for the cheap fare available any more. So you will most probably end up with the same total amount, when you book separately. An edge case could be, that a booking engine would choose the same more expensive fare for the whole booking, even e.g. one seat with the cheap fare would still be available.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought maybe it might be possible to trick the system by all choosing the cheap price at the same time, but probably not.

Comment: No, if the booking engine is not programmed very dumb, it will process booking requests sequentially at the end, and then simply reject the booking request for a cheaper fare, if it's not available any more.

Comment: Wouldn't you potentially pay more in taxes/fees if you booked separately, since some of those are flat fees per transaction and not percentages of the total cost? That might cause it to cost more *overall* if you book separately.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas This won't be the case for Ryanair, since they aren't allowed to charge extra fees (anymore).

Comment: I'm sure they still charge government and airport fees.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas These are per person not per booking.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas As Neusser says, none of that is per booking. I have (unfortunately) booked many Ryanair flights, there are no longer any per booking fees. The last to be eliminated would have been fees for using a credit card, which were banned for all transactions in the EU.